# Download React Class as .html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, classname

Here is an extremely simplified version of my React component:

```
export class SomePage extends Component {

  download() {
    // this needs to be downloaded as an .html file

    // is this the right way to go about it:
    let html = document.getElementsByClassName("second-child-div").innerHTML;

    // what else should be done here?
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="first-child-div">Stuff here</div>
        <div className="second-child-div" onClick={()=>this.download()}>
           <span className="some-other-styling-here">yada yada</span>
           More html elements, styling, and text here
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }

}
```

I want the user to be able to:

1. download `second-child-div` and
2. save it as an `.html` file ***with all of the styling intact*** (i.e. "some-other-styling-here", etc.)